# PHP script executes faster in browser than in python/another PHP script

Tags: php, python, curl

I wrote an API in PHP. It executes pretty fast for my purpose (**3s**) when I call it using the browser. However if I call it using another PHP script (which i wrote to do testing) it takes a looong time (24s) for each request! I use curl to call the URL. Anybody knows whats happening ?

System Config :

- Using WAMP to run the PHP.
- Hosted on local computer.

Solutions tried :

1. Disabled all firewalls
2. Added the option curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);

I even wrote a python script to call the PHP API and it also takes a long time. Seems like browser gives the best response time.

Any help is appreciated.

---

Updated with the code :

```
<?php

// Class to handle all Utilities
Class Utilities{

// Make a curl call to a URL and return both JSON & Array
public function callBing($bingUrl){
    //  Initiate curl   
    $ch = curl_init();
    // Disable SSL verification
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    // Will return the response, if false it print the response
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    // Set the url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$bingUrl);
    // Performance Tweak
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12');
    session_write_close();
    // Execute
    $bingJSON=curl_exec($ch);
    // Closing
    curl_close($ch);
    $bingArray = json_decode($bingJSON,true);
    return array( "array" => $bingArray , "json" => $bingJSON );
    }

}


?>

<?php
// The Test script
include_once('class/class.Utilities.php');

$util = new Utilities();

echo "<style> td { border : thin dashed black;}</style>";

    // Test JSON
    $testJSON = '
        {
            "data" : [
             { "A" : "24324" , "B" : "64767", "expectedValue" : "6.65" , "name" : "Test 1"},
             { "A" : "24324" , "B" : "65464", "expectedValue" : "14" , "name" : "Test 2"}
            ]
        }
    ';
    $testArray = json_decode($testJSON, TRUE);

    echo "<h1> Test Results </h1>";
    echo "<table><tr><th>Test name</th><th> Expected Value</th><th> Passed ? </th></tr>";
    $count = count($testArray["data"]);
    for ($i=0; $i < $count ; $i++) {
        $url = "http://localhost/API.php?txtA=".urlencode($testArray["data"][$i]["A"])."&txtB=".urlencode($testArray["data"][$i]["B"]);
        $result = $util->callutil($url);

        if($testArray["data"][$i]["expectedValue"] == $result["value"])
            $passed = true;
        else
            $passed = false;

        if($passed)
            $passed = "<span style='background:green;color: white;font-weight:bold;'>Passed</span>";
        else
            $passed = "<span style='background:red;color: white;font-weight:bold;'>Failed</span>";  


        echo "<tr><td>".$testArray["data"][$i]["name"]."</td><td>".$testArray["data"][$i]["expectedValue"]."</td><td>$passed</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: so, to be clear, all these calls are both to and from localhost?

Comment: Unless curl and python are set up very weirdly in your environment, then there's nothing I could think of without seeing some code.

Comment: Not sure whether this helps, try using ip instead of domain name and see whether it works.

Comment: it doesn't make sense that the request would take longer from one language than another. it's the same request either way. whatever else is in your code is what's causing the problem. you need to post code.

Comment: @Adelphia Yeah both calls are from and to localhost.

Answer (score 0):

There is an overhead cost involved in starting up the interpreter and parsing the code (whether php, python, ruby, etc). When you have the code running in a server process that startup cost is payed when the server starts initially, and the application logic (plus some minor request/response overhead) is simply executed on the request. When running the code manually, however, that additional startup overhead happens before you code can be run and causes the slowness you are seeing. This is the reason that mod_php, and mod_wsgi exist (as opposed to frameworks that use the CGI api).

Comment: He's not starting the code manually.  He's calling the script through curl, which starts a web request, which uses the exact same SAPI as it uses when called through the web browser.  Sorry, but gotta downvote for that, 'cause it's in the question.

Comment: ```However if I call it using another PHP script (which i wrote to do testing) ``` the OP is using a script to request the page. That script has a startup cost which is not incurred when you have a browser open and running.

Comment: Unless there is something very wrong with their system, a wrapper script does not add 20 seconds to a request.

Comment: Well I also don't see why rendering a php page would take 3 seconds so who knows what the OP is doing..

Comment: also, he never said it was just making and outputting a request. i bet he doing something with whatever data is returned in his test php script. that's probably what's causing the discrepancy. it might not be the request at all. that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @ChadSimmons : The 3s takes because there are other external calls and some processing. But that is very consistent 3s. The output of the API is a json which gets checked to see if the response is accurate.